# How to redefine a node expanding in a QTreeWidget?

Tags: qt, expand, qtreeview, qtreewidget

The way I understand the *qtreeview.cpp* the *expand* method in the QTreeView is responsible for expanding nodes. For example it is used in the *expandOrCollapseItemAtPos* method. I try to redefine a node expansion in the QTreeWidget:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QTreeWidget>
#include <QMessageBox>

class MyTree : public QTreeWidget
{
public:
    MyTree(QWidget *parent) : QTreeWidget(parent) {}
    expandItem(const QTreeWidgetItem *item) {
        QMessageBox msg;
        msg.setText("EXPAND ITEM!!");
        msg.exec();
        QTreeWidget::expandItem(item);
    }
    expand(const QModelIndex &index) {
        QMessageBox msg;
        msg.setText("EXPAND!!");
        msg.exec();
        QTreeWidget::expand(index);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget *mainWidget = new QWidget();
    mainWidget->resize(200,100);

    MyTree *myTree = new MyTree(mainWidget);
    myTree->resize(200,100);

    QTreeWidgetItem *node, *leaf;
    node = new QTreeWidgetItem(myTree);
    node->setText(0,"node");
    leaf = new QTreeWidgetItem(node);
    leaf->setText(0,"leaf");

    mainWidget->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

But there is no any message box when I expand a node. I tried to comment *QTreeWidget::expandItem(item);* and *QTreeWidget::expand(index);* but expanding is still working.
How do I redefine a node expanding in a QTreeWidget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*QTreeWidget::expand* and *QTreeWidget::expandItem* are non-virtual methods. So redefinition is not useful. I will use slot-signal mechanism with *QTreeWidget::expanded/collapsed* signals.

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(expanded(QModelIndex)), this, SLOT(myExpand(QModelIndex)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem -

```
connect(QTreeWidgetObject, SIGNAL(itemExpanded(QTreeWidgetItem*)), SLOT(slotItemExpanded(QTreeWidgetItem*)));
```

Comment: There is some mistakes. The slot of item expanding is QTreeWidget::expanded. And argument of this slot is QModelItems. I have update my answer.